# Custom SharePoint JavaScript field type

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, custom-field-type

I'm in the need to create a custom field type that renders like a LinkValue field. Instead of forwarding the browser to a different page, I would like to execute JavaScript code (in order to use OpenPopUpPage) depending on several parameters (maybe stored in SPFieldMultiColumnValue?).

What is the best way to approach the requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to be the best reference on custom field types from Bjorn Furuknap

[Customizing the User Experience of SharePoint: Custom fields deep dive](http://sharepointmagazine.net/articles/customizing-the-user-experience-of-sharepoint-custom-fields-deep-dive-part-5-of-6)

There is some pain involved in custom fields types though, [in his own words](http://blog.furuknap.net/question-why-are-there-always-two-constructors-in-a-sharepoint-custom-field-type-class)

> “Looking back I think it would have
>   been easier, and less painful, to eat
>   my own eyes.”

Comment: +1, This is indeed a nice post, but still does answer my question. I already know how to develop custom fields, but I am asking for the best way. Inheriting an already existing field, just changing the rendering template of such, etc etc.